# Show $\sup\{b^{-1/n}\} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to prove that if $b > 1$ then $\sup\{b^{-1/n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\} = 1$. It is part of the solution to exercise 6d in Principles of Mathematical Analysis on page 22 so I can't use any tools not introduced on pages prior. My work so far (lots of help from the internet):

If $b > 1$ then $b^{1/n} > 1$ and $b^{-1/n} < 1$. So 1 is an upper bound for $\{b^{-1/n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Next task is to show that no number smaller than 1 is an upper bound for the set. We'll use proof by contradiction. Introduce $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and $\delta > 0$ related so that $1 - \epsilon = \frac{1}{1 + \delta}$. Raising both sides by $n$
$$
(1 - \epsilon)^n = \frac{1}{(1 + \delta)^n} \leq \frac{1}{1+n\delta}
$$
for sufficiently large $n$. That makes it clear that $(1 - \epsilon)^n < b$ holds and therefore $1 - \epsilon < b^{1/n}$. But how to proceed? I want to show that $1 - \epsilon < b^{-1/n}$.

**Edit**: Fixed proof:

Proof by contradiction shows that there can be no upper bound smaller than 1 for $B$.
Suppose that there is an $0 < \alpha < 1$ so that which is an upper bound for $B$. Then
$$
  \frac{1}{b^{1/n}} < \alpha \iff \frac{1}{\alpha^n} < b. 
$$
If we pick an arbitrary number so that $b = 35$, we get
$$
  \frac{1}{\alpha^n} < 35.
$$
Then it is clear that for any $0 < \alpha < 1$, we can pick a large enough $n$ to falsify the inequality. Therefore we have a contradiction and $\sup B$ must be 1.

Comment: "... and therefore $1-\epsilon<b^{1/n}$" - "I want to show that $1-\epsilon<b^{-1/n}$" - What is your problem?

Comment: Suppose there is some $\epsilon>0$ for which $b^{-1/n}<1-\epsilon$ for all $n$. Then $b>{1\over (1-\epsilon)^n}$. But $1-\epsilon<1$, so the right-hand-side is unbounded as $n\to\infty$, which is a contradiction

Comment: @Munchhausen Where in lies the contradiction?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist The contradiction is that ${1\over (1-\epsilon)^n}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. However, we know that $b>{1\over(1-\epsilon)^n}$ for every $n$ by assumption. This is impossible

Comment: @Munchhausen Oh, I see. So I could essentially have taken $b=35$ (random number) and shown that the assumption leads to a contradiction?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Yes, since ${1\over(1-\epsilon)^n}\to\infty$, for every $N\in\mathbb{R}$, there is some $n_0$ for which ${1\over(1-\epsilon)^n}>N$ for all $n\geq n_0$. In particular, this holds for $N=b$, so that's our contradiction

Comment: @Munchhausen Oh I see, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to show that the inequality $1/\alpha^n<b$ can't hold for all $n$ to get the desired contradiction. And this is not difficult given your first proof.

Note that $1/\alpha>1$ and hence $1/\alpha =1+h,h>0$ and $1/\alpha ^n=(1+h) ^n>1+nh$ and this will exceed $b$ as soon as $n>(b-1)/h$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(b^{-1/n})$ is increasing (take the logarithm). Since it's bounded, it converges to its supremum. But the sequence converges to 1 (because its logarithm converges to zero). Therefore the sup is 1.

Comment: Logarithms haven't been introduced in the book yet.

Comment: Actually, you can prove that $b^{-1/n}$ is increasing and converges to 1 without the logarithm